# Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Got this error message in Next.js but have no idea what to do with this. Next.js version 13.0.5.

I was passing a prop to a client component in Next.js. Prop is the list of objects, and one of the values is a function. But the question is, what this error message means?

> Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server"

How can I expose a function by marking it with "use server"?

```
matchesColumns.push({ field: 'pk', headerName: "", flex: 0.3, renderCell: (params, event) => (<Link href={`/matches/${encodeURIComponent(params.row.pk)}`}>Details</Link>) });
(...)
{<Tabela2 rows={matchesRows} columns={matchesColumns}/>}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a new upcoming Next.js feature called server actions.

You can use server actions to pass async functions from **server** to **client** components while having them still be callable from client.

Here's an example:

```
// page.tsx

"use server";

import { ClientComponent } from './ClientComponent.tsx';

async function deleteItem(itemId: string) {
  "use server"; // mark function as a server action (fixes the error)

  // TODO add item deletion logic
  return null;
}

export function Page() {
  return <ClientComponent deleteItem={deleteItem} />
}
```

```
// ClientComponent.tsx

export function ClientComponent({ deleteItem }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={async () => {
      await deleteItem("foobar");
      alert("item has been deleted");
    }}>
      delete item
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! on NextJS version 13.4.19 this code gives "Server actions must be async functions", and making Page() async gives the error in the question again.
To fix it remove the first "use server".

Comment: How come are you able to use an async function in a client component? ```Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.```

Answer (score 8):

If you encounter this error in a `error.(jsx|tsx)` file, note that the `error.(jsx|tsx)` files must be marked as a client component.

[Documentation reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

***Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
<... src=... width={350} height={350} alt=... loader={function}>***

### Does your error look like this?

*note: this error did not occur when I used same methods @/components/Products.tsx, and imported a component named "ProductCard" inside it, it only happened when tried to do it in a dynamic page with imported component "singleProduct"> see codes below for details*

#### TLDR:

**there was a component that would display a single product. That function was giving this error.**
**Solution: "use client" where the error was occuring**

This **"SingleProduct"** component (which takes a prop) was called inside a page name **"ProductDetailView**" [a dynamic route] which by default should be server rendered , where the single product was fetched from api call.

After doing every thing else like enabling server action, I just wrote "use client" on the single product component and all error went way.

I believe mine happened because I was fetching the data in a dynamic page which was server side but the component was client side. But not sure. if any one know whats going on please let me know. [btw I am noob]

```
"dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "20.4.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
    "lucide-react": "^0.263.1",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.6",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
```

All codes are as it is.

for ui > shadcn/ui
*route > @/ProductDetailView/[id]/page.tsx*

```
// product component
// by deafult should be server

import { ProductProps } from "@/components/Products";
import axios from "axios";
import SingleProduct from "@/components/SingleProduct";


export async function getSingleProducts ( id: string ) {

    const res = await axios.get( `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${ id }`, {
        // timeout after 5 seconds
        // signal: AbortSignal.timeout( 5000 ),
    } )
        .then( response => { return response.data } )
        .catch( err => alert( err ) )

    return res;
}

export default async function ProductDetailView ( { params }: { params: { id: string } } ) {

    const product: ProductProps = await getSingleProducts( params.id );

    return (
        <main className="text-center text-gray-200">
            <SingleProduct props={ product }></SingleProduct>
        </main>
    )
}
```

*route > @/components/SignleProduct*

```
// adding use client solves the issue.
"use client"
import { ProductProps } from "@/components/Products";
import {
    Card,
    CardContent,
    CardDescription,
    CardFooter,
    CardHeader,
    CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card"
import Image from "next/image";

export default function SingleProduct ( { props }: { props: ProductProps } ) {


    const imgLink = ( src: string ) => {
        const image = src.substring( src.indexOf( "img" ) );
        return image
    }

    // beautifully parse it in a variable
    const imgSrc = imgLink( props.image );

    // now the loader
    // always destructure src or an object will be returned 
    const imageLoader = ( { src }: any ) => {
        const imgString = `https://fakestoreapi.com/${ src }`
        return imgString;
    }


    return (
        <main className="text-center text-gray-200">
            <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                    <CardTitle>{ props.title }</CardTitle>
                    <CardDescription>{ props.description }</CardDescription>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardContent>
                    <Image
                        src={ imgSrc }
                        width={ 350 }
                        height={ 350 }
                        alt={ props.title }
                        loader={ imageLoader }
                    >

                    </Image>
                </CardContent>
                <CardFooter>
                    <p>{ props.price }</p>
                    <p>{ props.category }</p>
                </CardFooter>
            </Card>

        </main>
    )
}
```

**The error did not happen when I did this.**

*route > @/component/Products*

```
// wanted to show all products here
import axios from "axios"
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard"

export type ProductProps = {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    price: number,
    category: string,
    description: string,
    image: string
}

export async function getProducts () {


    const res = await axios.get( "https://fakestoreapi.com/products", {
        // timeout after 5 seconds
        // signal: AbortSignal.timeout( 5000 ),
    } )
        .then( response => { return response.data } )
        .catch( err => alert( err ) )

    return res;
}

export default async function Products () {


    const products: ProductProps[] = await getProducts();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-50">
                Products Count : { products.length };
            </h1>

            <div className="m-5 grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 justify-center items-center">
                {
                    products.map( product => {
                        return (
                            <div key={ product.id } className="col-auto ">
                                <ProductCard props={ product }></ProductCard>
                            </div>
                        )
                    } )
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

**Product Card**

```
// this is product card

import {
    Card,
    CardContent,
    CardDescription,
    CardFooter,
    CardHeader,
    CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card"
import { ProductProps } from "./Products"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from "next/image"


export default function ProductCard ( { props }: { props: ProductProps } ) {

    // an elaborated way to get an external image to display
    // if we do this then we don't need to add config inside next.config.js
    // first get the last part of the url as src

    const imgLink = ( src: string ) => {
        const image = src.substring( src.indexOf( "img" ) );
        return image
    }

    // beautifully parse it in a variable
    const imgSrc = imgLink( props.image );

    // now the loader
    // always destructure src or an object will be returned 
    const imageLoader = ( { src }: any ) => {
        const imgString = `https://fakestoreapi.com/${ src }`
        return imgString;
    }

    // clip the description

    const textClip = ( src: string ) => {
        const text = src.substring( 0, 100 );
        return text
    }


    //  parse it in a variable
    const textClipped = textClip( props.description );

    // clip the title

    const titleClip = ( src: string ) => {
        const title = src.substring( 0, 100 );
        return title
    }


    //  parse it in a variable
    const titleClipped = titleClip( props.title );

    return (

        <Card className="flex justify-center items-center h-[300px] bg-slate-950 text-slate-200">
            <CardContent className="flex justify-center items-center">
                <div className="w-auto h-auto pt-6">
                    <Image
                        loader={ imageLoader }
                        src={ `${ imgSrc }` }
                        alt={ props.title }
                        width={ 340 }
                        height={ 340 }
                        layout="responsive"
                        style={ { objectFit: "contain" } }
                    >

                    </Image>
                </div>
            </CardContent>
            <section className=" flex items-start justify-center flex-col">
                <CardHeader className="pb-1 pt-0">
                    <CardTitle className="text-start text-lg">

                        {/* <LinkIcon size={ 40 } spacing={ 10 }></LinkIcon> */ }

                        <Link href={ `/ProductDetailView/${ props.id }` } target="_blank">
                            <p>{ titleClipped }...</p>
                        </Link>

                    </CardTitle>
                    <CardDescription>{ textClipped }...</CardDescription>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardContent className="p-0 ps-6">
                    <p>Category: { props.category }</p>
                </CardContent>
                <CardFooter className="p-0 ps-6" >
                    <p>${ props.price }</p>
                </CardFooter>
            </section>
        </Card>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this would help anyone but i had a similar issues when trying to build my nextjs app (version 13.4.5) the issue was specifically this.

> Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".

followed by some props in curly braces

> {parallelRouterKey: ..., segmentPath: ..., error: function, errorStyles: ..., loading: ..., loadingStyles: ..., hasLoading}

NOTE: i wasn't using server actions nor trying to implement it in any way beacause it was still in alpha testing as at time of writing this.

so i resolved the issue by making the error.tsx file in my root directory(the only error file in my project) a client component.

```
"use client"

const Error = ({ error, reset }: { error: Error; reset: () => void }) => {
  return (
    <div className=""></div>
       )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example:

```
// components/form.tsx
'use client';
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Form(props: { action: Function, className?: string }) {
    const { action, className } = props;
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    return (
        <form className={`${className} flex flex-col mb-4 p-10`} onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            action(value);
        }}>
            <input className="block w-full px-3 py-2 text-lg border border-green-500 bg-gray-50"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Type anything!"
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setValue(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
        </form >
    )
}
```

and

```
// app/page.tsx
import Form from "@/components/form";

export default async function Home() {
  const formAction = async (data: string) => {
    'use server';
    console.log(data);
  }
  return (
    <main className="w-full h-screen bg-white">
      <Form action={formAction} className="max-w-2xl mx-auto"></Form>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: As it's currently written your answer is a little unclear, you could improve this answer by including explanations as to how this fixes the issue