# Passing render props not working in next13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to build a custom component for Contentful's live preview feature in Next 13 and the app directory. My idea is to create a client component which accepts a data prop, type-safe by allowing a generic type to be passed down. Like this:

**LivePreviewWrapper.tsx**

```
'use client'

import { useContentfulLiveUpdates } from '@contentful/live-preview/react'

const isFunction = <T extends CallableFunction = CallableFunction>(value: unknown): value is T =>
  typeof value === 'function'

export const runIfFunction = <T, U>(valueOrFn: T | ((...fnArgs: U[]) => T), ...args: U[]) => {
  return isFunction(valueOrFn) ? valueOrFn(...args) : valueOrFn
}

type MaybeRenderProp<P> = React.ReactNode | ((props: P) => React.ReactNode)

type LivePreviewWrapperProps<T> = {
  children: MaybeRenderProp<{
    updatedData: T
  }>
  data: T
}

export const LivePreviewWrapper = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>({
  children,
  data
}: LivePreviewWrapperProps<T>) => {
  const updatedData = useContentfulLiveUpdates<T>(data, { locale: 'en-US' })

  return runIfFunction(children, { updatedData })
}
```

I can then pull this into a page component, pass the data I pull from Contentful down, include the type, and then get the live updates. But, when I try and run it this way in a page component, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
  <... data={{...}} children={function}>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is what my page component looks like:

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

import { ContentfulCta, type ContentfulCtaProps } from '~/components/contentful/cta'
import { ContentfulGrid, type ContentfulGridProps } from '~/components/contentful/grid'
import { ContentfulHero, type ContentfulHeroProps } from '~/components/contentful/hero'
import { ContentfulHighlight, type ContentfulHighlightProps } from '~/components/contentful/highlight'
import { ContentfulHorizontalTabs, type ContentfulHorizontalTabsProps } from '~/components/contentful/horizontal-tabs'
import { ContentfulSpeaker, type ContentfulSpeakerProps } from '~/components/contentful/speaker'
import { ContentfulTextSession, type ContentfulTextSessionProps } from '~/components/contentful/text'
import { LogoList } from '~/components/marketing/logo-list'
import { LivePreviewWrapper } from '~/components/shared/live-preview-wrapper'
import { getContentfulParams, getPageBySlug, type ContentfulPage } from '~/models/contentful'
import { ContentfulProvider } from '~/providers/contentful'
import { type TypePageSkeleton } from '~/types/generated/contentful'
import { type PageParamsWithSearch } from '~/types/helpers'
import { formatParamsSlug } from '~/utils/core'

import '@contentful/live-preview/style.css'

type LandingPageParams = PageParamsWithSearch<{ slug: string[] }>

export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
  const pages = await getContentfulParams<TypePageSkeleton>('page')

  return pages.items.map((page) => ({
    params: {
      slug: formatParamsSlug(page.fields.slug)
    }
  }))
}

export const revalidate = 60
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default async function ContentfulLandingPage({ params, searchParams }: LandingPageParams) {
  const isDraftMode = searchParams?.draftMode === 'enabled'
  const data = await getPageBySlug({ slug: params.slug, isDraftMode })

  if (!data) {
    notFound()
  }

  return (
    <ContentfulProvider>
      <main className='pb-8 lg:pb-12'>
        <LivePreviewWrapper<ContentfulPage> data={data}>
          {({ updatedData }) => {
            return (
              <div className='space-y-8'>
                {updatedData.fields.body.map((entry) => {
                  if (!entry) return null
                  switch (entry.sys.contentType.sys.id) {
                    case 'hero': {
                      return <ContentfulHero key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHeroProps} />
                    }

                    case 'highlightSession': {
                      return <ContentfulHighlight key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHighlightProps} />
                    }

                    case 'grid': {
                      return <ContentfulGrid key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulGridProps} />
                    }

                    case 'textSession': {
                      return <ContentfulTextSession key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulTextSessionProps} />
                    }

                    case 'speaker': {
                      return <ContentfulSpeaker key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulSpeakerProps} />
                    }

                    case 'cta': {
                      return <ContentfulCta key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulCtaProps} />
                    }

                    case 'horizontalTabs': {
                      return (
                        <ContentfulHorizontalTabs key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHorizontalTabsProps} />
                      )
                    }

                    case 'customersLogos': {
                      return <LogoList key={entry.sys.id} />
                    }

                    default:
                      console.warn(entry.sys.contentType, 'was not handled')
                      return null
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )
          }}
        </LivePreviewWrapper>
      </main>
    </ContentfulProvider>
  )
}
```

I don't understand why this error is being returned; does anyone have a better idea how to fix it, I don't know what else to try. It seems to be something with the `useContentfulLiveUpdates` hook, but the type of `updatedData` is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are not serialisable in Next.js at this stage. Render props work RSC -> RSC or RCC -> RCC but not RSC -> RCC yet it seems. In this case, it looks to me that the compiler could easily be made to be smart enough to handle this case but I think Next.js 13 app dir and RSC need some time to mature.

It would appear to me that creating an intermediary client component would work.

```
"use client"
// ... 

export const MyLivePreview = ({ data }: { data: WhateverDataType }) => <LivePreviewWrapper<ContentfulPage> data={data}>
          {({ updatedData }) => {
            return (
              <div className='space-y-8'>
                {updatedData.fields.body.map((entry) => {
                  if (!entry) return null
                  switch (entry.sys.contentType.sys.id) {
                    case 'hero': {
                      return <ContentfulHero key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHeroProps} />
                    }

                    case 'highlightSession': {
                      return <ContentfulHighlight key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHighlightProps} />
                    }

                    case 'grid': {
                      return <ContentfulGrid key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulGridProps} />
                    }

                    case 'textSession': {
                      return <ContentfulTextSession key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulTextSessionProps} />
                    }

                    case 'speaker': {
                      return <ContentfulSpeaker key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulSpeakerProps} />
                    }

                    case 'cta': {
                      return <ContentfulCta key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulCtaProps} />
                    }

                    case 'horizontalTabs': {
                      return (
                        <ContentfulHorizontalTabs key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHorizontalTabsProps} />
                      )
                    }

                    case 'customersLogos': {
                      return <LogoList key={entry.sys.id} />
                    }

                    default:
                      console.warn(entry.sys.contentType, 'was not handled')
                      return null
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )
          }}
        </LivePreviewWrapper>
```

Then,

```
export default async function ContentfulLandingPage({ params, searchParams }: LandingPageParams) {
  const isDraftMode = searchParams?.draftMode === 'enabled'
  const data = await getPageBySlug({ slug: params.slug, isDraftMode })

  if (!data) {
    notFound()
  }

  return (
    <ContentfulProvider>
      <main className='pb-8 lg:pb-12'>
        <MyLivePreview data={data} />
      </main>
    </ContentfulProvider>
  )
}
```

Annoyingly, for my experience using Next.js 13 app dir, a lot of code splitting is required. I would imagine the compiler will become smarter to know what server and what's client.

Let me know if this helps (noting that I did not actually test any of this). Otherwise will be happy to help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I’ve had this working before with this exact model, but it takes away the reusability I’m looking to have with the component. Might be something I can integrate down the road I guess.

Answer (score 0):

using useServer hook might solve you issue, please check the code and for futhur reference I am attaching the links

Stack overflow:[Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75676177/error-functions-cannot-be-passed-directly-to-client-components-unless-you-expli)

next Doc:https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components

github :https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47846

```
// page.tsx

"use server";

import { ClientComponent } from './ClientComponent.tsx';

async function deleteItem(itemId: string) {
  "use server"; // mark function as a server action (fixes the error)

  // TODO add item deletion logic
  return null;
}

export function Page() {
  return <ClientComponent deleteItem={deleteItem} />
}
// ClientComponent.tsx

export function ClientComponent({ deleteItem }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={async () => {
      await deleteItem("foobar");
      alert("item has been deleted");
    }}>
      delete item
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/contentful/live-preview/tree/main/examples/next-13-app-router-ssr, it's an example of doing Contentful live preview with React Server Components/the `app` router.

The key is to not try and use the client-side only approach of a provider and live updates, but instead to reload the page when the Contentful live preview package detects a change:

Conditionally include an external script (you'll need to bundle this yourself and add it in the `public` directory):

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const { isEnabled } = draftMode();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      {isEnabled && <Script src="/live-preview.mjs" />}
    </html>
  );
}
```

Then in the script listen for changes:

```js
import { ContentfulLivePreview } from '@contentful/live-preview';

ContentfulLivePreview.init({ locale: 'en-US', debugMode: true, enableLiveUpdates: true });
ContentfulLivePreview.subscribe('save', {
  callback: () => {
    window.location.reload();
  },
});
```

I've not tried this myself yet, but when I implement live preview instead of using `window.location.reload()` and having a full page reload, I might see if I can fire off a custom DOM event that a React client component listens for and calls [`router.refresh()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter) instead of `window.location.reload()`.

Answer (score -2):

Add useServer like this:

```
const MyLiveComponent = ({ updatedData }) => {
  return (
    <div className='space-y-8'>
      {updatedData.fields.body.map((entry) => {
                  if (!entry) return null
                  switch (entry.sys.contentType.sys.id) {
                    case 'hero': {
                      return <ContentfulHero key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHeroProps} />
                    }

                    case 'highlightSession': {
                      return <ContentfulHighlight key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHighlightProps} />
                    }

                    case 'grid': {
                      return <ContentfulGrid key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulGridProps} />
                    }

                    case 'textSession': {
                      return <ContentfulTextSession key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulTextSessionProps} />
                    }

                    case 'speaker': {
                      return <ContentfulSpeaker key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulSpeakerProps} />
                    }

                    case 'cta': {
                      return <ContentfulCta key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulCtaProps} />
                    }

                    case 'horizontalTabs': {
                      return (
                        <ContentfulHorizontalTabs key={entry.sys.id} entry={entry as ContentfulHorizontalTabsProps} />
                      )
                    }

                    case 'customersLogos': {
                      return <LogoList key={entry.sys.id} />
                    }

                    default:
                      console.warn(entry.sys.contentType, 'was not handled')
                      return null
                  }
                })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function ContentfulLandingPage({ params, searchParams }: LandingPageParams) {
const isDraftMode = searchParams?.draftMode === 'enabled'
  const data = await getPageBySlug({ slug: params.slug, isDraftMode })

  if (!data) {
    notFound()
  }
  return (
    <ContentfulProvider>
      <main className='pb-8 lg:pb-12'>
        <LivePreviewWrapper<ContentfulPage> data={data}>
          {useServer(() => <MyLiveComponent />)}
        </LivePreviewWrapper>
      </main>
    </ContentfulProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useServer` is not, as far as I can tell, an active or existing package. Doesn't do much to help in this case, plus this doesn't meaningfully address the code as it's written in my original question.